# failed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello here is my component

```
var Tile = ({product}) => (
<Col lg={4} md={4} sm={6} xs={12} className="image-block">
    <div className="image-block-body" style={
        { background: 'url(' + decodeURIComponent(product.PictureUri) + ')', backgroundSize: '100% 100%' }}>
        <p>{product.Name} </p>
    </div>
</Col>);
```

It gives me correct URI on web site

[image]

But web browser throws exception like this
[image]

How to fix this?

EDITED:
Here is how => [Yii2 Not allowed to load local resource (Image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685886/yii2-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-image)

Comment: What's the value of `product.PictureUri`?

Comment: just correct URI like this `...\Content\ProductsGalleries\2bf03d6d-e833-41d3-9eb7-b161c3f69d3e\1.jpg`

Comment: Why don't you just put that URL in instead of trying to decode something that isn't encoded?

Comment: `decodeURIComponent('\\Content\\ProductsGalleries\\2bf03d6d-e833-41d3-9eb7-b161cf69d3e\\1.jpg')` doesn't produce `%5CContent%5CProductsGalleries%5C2bf03d6d-e833-41d3-9eb7-b161c3f69d3e%5C1.jpg` so what you are saying cannot be right. Please tell us: What is the value of `product.PictureUri` ?

Comment: I edited the post. `DecodeURIComponent` function does nothing there and its wrong usage. Value of `product.PictureUri` its just correct URI

Comment: Ah. So the issue has nothing to do with what you said in the title. The browser is not allowed to load resources from local disk. Did you try to search? [`[javascript] not allowed to load local resource`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+not+allowed+to+load+local+resource)

Comment: But why it trying to access with wrong URI? But thanks for the link, now Im understand.